# Bloomberg excel add-in BDH

Tags: excel, excel-addins, bloomberg

I was given a funds prices historical database from 2000 to nov/2020 using the BDH function of Bloomberg's excel add-in. The problem is that there are many cases where a fund repeats last price from funds extintion 'till nov/2020.

For example, lets say a fund was extinted in 2015 at a price of 5.25, then 5.25 is shown from 2015 to nov/2020, which is clearly useless.

I want to know if it is a problem caused by BDH function parameterization or this function always outputs information like this.

Below is an image of a section of the database

[image: 1]

Comment: Why does it matter? You could alter the data to remove all duplicates bar one and then any query reports the last stated value. All you get is a (slightly) smaller data set.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `Day` and `Fill` overrides? It may also be that tthe fund kept reporting a price to Bloomberg after it was closed and the data is actually there so you will have to get rid of it manually (or using a condition on extinction date if you can retrieve that).

Comment: Yeah, actually I am trying to avoid that kind of task, specially because I would have to define some criteria to identify when a price is not changing. For example, sometimes Bloomberg reports same price for a given period which then start to change again, therefore I would have to determine wich case is occurring. To put it simple, it may hide come real problmes over the data.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually thinking it might be a problem with the **Fill** parameter, is just that right now I don't hace access to bloomberg terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an override `Fill=P`, change it to `Fill=N/A` for example. That will fill days without a price with N/A instead of using the last known price.

And if you are using `Days` with N, W, C or A, remove it or replace it with `Days=T` to only include actual trading days.

You can find more info on the overrides by typing `=BDH()` in a cell, selecting the cell and selecting `More Functions...` in Excel - that will open a popup where you have a link "Help on this function" which as all the parameters.